# Ultralow interest rates and bubbles

Tags: monetary-policy, interest-rate, economic-bubble

We've had ultralow interest rates for a very long time now (I think unprecedented in history). Is it possible that this extremely loose monetary policy is creating bubbles? Bill Gross has put out a warning: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/bill-gross-negative-yields-will-lead-to-supernova-like-market-implosion-2016-06-10

Is it possible he is right? What would be the impact on the economy? What will the FED do if this happens, do they have other policy-tools besides QE and lowering interest rates?

thanks in advance